# How to do GetFeatureInfo in OpenLayers2

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, wms, fields-attributes, getfeatureinfo

I am new to OpenLayers and I want to add `OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo` to get the feature info to website, but I can't figure out right method.

I also see the source code of GeoServer OpenLayers page and still I can't find the syntax of `OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo` code?

I use GeoServer, Apache-Tomcat-6.0.35 and OpenLayers 2.10. Should I use proxy to call OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo?

This is my GeoServer WMS URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/sac/wms?
service=WMS&
version=1.1.0&
request=GetMap&
layers=sac:contour&
styles=&
bbox=187754.5,204980.703125,192031.40625,210022.890625&
width=434&height=512&s
rs=EPSG:5235&
format=application/openlayers
```

Please give me sample code which calls `OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo`?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you see the source code but you can't find the code? Please don't just ask for "code", be very specific in what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can check this [example](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/getfeatureinfo-control.html) on openlayers.

```
    OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "proxy.cgi?url=";

    var map;

    function load() {
        map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
            maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(143.834,-43.648,148.479,-39.573)
        });

        var political = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("State Boundaries",
            "http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms", 
            {'layers': 'topp:tasmania_state_boundaries', 
transparent: true, format: 'image/gif'},
            {isBaseLayer: true}
        );
        };

        map.addLayer(political);
```

if it didnt help you, you can read [Open Layer with GeoSever](http://khayer.wordpress.com/2010/07/14/open-layer-with-geosever/) example.

**EDIT:**

for wms get info function you have to add this code to which i have gave before:

```
info = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
            url: 'http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms', 
            title: 'Identify features by clicking',
            queryVisible: true,
            eventListeners: {
                getfeatureinfo: function(event) {
                    map.addPopup(new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                        "chicken", 
                        map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy),
                        null,
                        event.text,
                        null,
                        true
                    ));
                }
            }
        });
        map.addControl(info);
        info.activate();
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: I look your links and those are really helpful.I change the question

Comment: @sacprasanna if the first post work for you, pls set it accepted and then ask another question for another people who want to profit by this answer...and for your new question i have updated my answer..

Comment: Ok,Yes it is the good way

Comment: Good one. But this gives muliple feature info. How to close previous popup and reload new one on next click.